# JSON array within an array

Tags: ajax, json, api

im working with a JSON object  [here](http://imvdb.com/api/v1/search/videos?q=U2), i want to access the images, its an array within the array of 'results'. I know i have to loop, but not sure if im doing it correctly

[image]

My Code

```
function getVideos(art) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://imvdb.com/api/v1/search/videos?q=' + art,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data.albums.name));
            $('#videos').empty();
            $.each(data.results.image, function (index, element) {
                //alert(element.name);
                $('#videos').append(element.results.image+ '<br/>');

            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#videos').html('<h3>Error in retrieval</h3>');
        }
    });

}
```

UPDATE when i just code

```
 $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                //alert(element.name);
                $('#videos').append(element.results+ '<br/>');

            });
```

i get 
[image]

UPDATE:

it works for me now i just was accessing results instead of images

```
$.each(data.results, function (index, element) {
                //alert(element.name);
                $('#videos').append(element.image.o + '<br/>');

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your `$.each` you already take it down to the level of `data.results.image`, and then you are looking for `results.image` within that. So to your jQuery script you are looking for every single `data.results.image.results.image`, and that doesn't exist. To loop through every `results` object, you need to do an `$.each` on `data.results` then look for `element.image`.

Here is a working JSFiddle which demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/7udv3uoh/4/

Comment: Thanks mate, i figured that in the end

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

it works for me now i just was accessing results instead of images

```
$.each(data.results, function (index, element) {
                //alert(element.name);
                $('#videos').append(element.image.o + '<br/>');

            });
```